# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, Convert text in the file to UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a large text file having some content written in Hindi and german language. I want to convert every single special character to UTF-8 encoding. (line by line)

I was using this code but it is giving me an error as :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:566)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:181)
    at ConvertUTF.main(ConvertUTF.java:47)

This is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ConvertUTF {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {

            InputStream is = null;
            is = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF8"));

            int str;


            char[] cbuf = new char[is.available()];
            int i=1;
            StringBuilder sb1 = new
                    StringBuilder("");
            while ((str = (in.read(cbuf,0,8))) != 0 && i<7) {
                sb1.append(cbuf);


            }

            System.out.print(sb1);

            in.close();



            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }


}
```

Comment: The Exception is being thrown when you append to your StringBuilder.  Per your description, the File is large.  Consider writing the converted text into a separate File rather than trying to build the entire text in memory.

Comment: I did that already it ended up creating a large file and the loop didn't stop

Comment: I would fully expect a large output file because the input file is large and you are changing the encoding on various characters.  You reported an OutOfMemoryException.   The loop not terminating is a different problem.  I would assume that your stop condition is off - I believe end-of-stream is indicated by -1.

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream("file.txt"), "UTF-8"));`

try with `UTF-8`instead of `UTF8`

Comment: I did, but the same output is coming.

Comment: maybe a problem with the original text ... are you sure about the encoded result you should get  ? You can paste your text to an online converter like this one : https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-encode

Comment: The expected output should look something like this `\xe0\xa6\xac\xe0\xa6\x99\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\x97\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbf\x20\xe0\xa6\xa8\xe0\xa6\xae\xe0\xa7\x81\xe0\xa6\xa8\xe0\xa6\xbe\x20\xe0\xa6\xaa\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\xa0\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\xaf`

Comment: But i am getting the same output as the text i input.

Comment: did you try the online converter ? Not sure UTF-8 will help you here

Comment: yes i used the online converter. It gave me the output as \xe0 . 
but when i am running my script on the terminal it is giving me the same output string as i am inputting.

Comment: do you have a reproducer ? Git repo ?

Comment: Yes. I do have a GitHub rep.

Comment: please share so I can take a look

Comment: Clone with : https://github.com/neishka998/ConvertText2UTF.git

Answer (score 0):

there is a mistake in the normalization name : Change UTF8 to UTF-8

Comment: I did, but the same output is coming.

Comment: try to change the jvm default propertie like this : System.setPropery("file.encoding","UTF-8");

Comment: it is giving me the same string as i am giving as input.